# I am selling a range of products by installment payments and trying to forecast allocation of payments to Cost/Tax and Profit

Tags: sql, sql-server, forecasting, retention

I am selling a range of products and have the cost price, sale price and tax stored in separate table.

My customers are paying by installments and I want to forecast the allocation of the future payments to the following:

- The product cost
- The sales tax
- My profit

One issue is that payments could need to be split against different types of retention.

In the example below I am selling a product for £120 which has a cost of £50 and I will need to pay sales tax of £10 leaving a profit of £60.

The customer is paying £20 / mth and I want to forecast allocating the payments to each category.

This will enable me to forecast the profits of the business over the following months.

```
Sales price £120
Cost £50
Tax £10
Profit £60
Paying £20 / math
1st Jan £20 Cost
1st Feb £20 Cost 
1st Mar £10 Cost
1st Mar £10 Tax
1st Apr £20 Profit
1st May £20 Profit
1st Jun £20 Profit
```

There are obviously a number of products and I would like to run some SQL to do the forecast.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Apologies. Using SQL Server. The question is how would I go about doing this? Would I use cases statements, varaibles ? I've tried a few things and keep going round in circles.

Comment: Are you planning to forecast out a known amount of time or just the life of the installment plan, Also, I bet you will need to row group by PK and forecast/accounting property and column wise by date for the accounting property values.

Comment: Hi Ross. Yes I'm looking to forecast by all time so  I have a complete data table which I can then apply limits to in reporting.Thanks. Simon